# How to transfer table data in another table of a certain ID

Tags: php, html, mysql

```
<?php
    $host = 'localhost';
    $user ='root';
    $pass = '';
    $db = 'sad';
    $con =mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$db);

    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>ADMIN</title>
        <style>
        table,th,td
        {
        border: 1.5px solid black;
        }
        </style>
        <script>
            function approve()
            {
                <?php

                  $hide = $_POST['omg'];
                  $qwe = "INSERT INTO `enrolled` SELECT * FROM `new` WHERE `id` = '$hide' ";



                ?>


            }
        </script>
        </head>
    <body>
        <form method='POST'>
            <table width=500px >


                <?php 

                $sql = "SELECT * FROM New";
                $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
                if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

                echo "<form method='POST'><tr><td>ID: " . $row["id"]. "<br>FIRSTNAME: " . $row["fname"]. "<br>MIDDLENAME: " . $row["mname"]. "<br>LASTNAME : " . $row["lname"]. "<br>COURSE: " . $row["course"]. "<br>ADDRESS: " . $row["address"]. "<br>CONTACT: " . $row["contact"] . "<br><br><input type='text' name='omg' value=$row[id]> <input type='button' name= 'btn' value='Approve' onclick=approve()></td></tr></form>";

                }
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "No Request Sent!";
                }
                ?>



            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Im having a problem on copying a certain data of a table and transfer it into another table. this code $qwe = "INSERT INTO `enrolled` SELECT * FROM `new` is working and outputs all data contains by table 'New' and  if i place WHERE id = '$hide' ; the database 'enrolled' shows nothing.

Comment: Off-topic but don't use string interpolation with SQL queries as it makes them vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: @ext , sorry mate . but i cant understand "string interpolation" . im still a student . my instructor does not teach that on us . could you please explain to me ?

Comment: Consider what would happen if `$hide` was set to `'; DROP TABLE enrolled --`. PHP has [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) with [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: Do you want to copy your result of your select statement in another table, right? Its a table in your database or did you want to send your data into another system? And a hint, you try to use PHP in a JavaScript function... think about it, it if will work

Comment: i want to copy a table data in another table and does php work in javascript function ? i thought i works :/ could you help me man ? @ToyRobotic

Comment: php in javascipt, works dude

Comment: @zxc if its an php file, then it will be work, but you try to use php code inside a javascript function like its javascript. Lets me explain When you try to call your js function, you believe that the php code inside the function will be run, but it didt'! A would recommend that you will be look how javascript will be work and how php is working and why your php code is not running, when you call your js function ;)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work. First, select your dataset and then build the new insert query and in your loop. It's not the best solution, but hopefully you will understand the concept behinde this. But maybe you need a update query ... when you want to "insert" data at a specfic point. If you want only to copy youre data. This should work.

```
<?php
$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$database = 'sad';
$connection = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $database);


$query = "SELECT * FROM New";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $query = 'INSERT INTO `enrolled` (id, fname, mname, lname, course, address, contact) 
                  VALUES
                  (\'' . $row['id'] . ' \', \'' . $row['fname'] . ' \', \'' . $row['mname'] . ' \', \'' . $row['lname'] . ' \', \'' . $row['course'] . ' \', \'' . $row['address'] . ' \', \'' . $row['contact'] . '\')';
        mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    }
```

Comment: I didn't test it and did not check the syntax. Its only show you, how a solution for your problem could be work. I guess when you only want to copy data without modifcation, then you should solve this task only with sql.

Comment: @zxc when my post helps you or is a acceptable solution, let the community know it and vote my post up or mark it as solution. thx.

Comment: i can copy all table data @ToyRobtic , but the thing i need is to copy a data row WHERE Id= '$hide;'

Comment: Then add "WHERE Id= ..." to the query. Is the problme, that you didn't know how to get user input to $hide?

Comment: the variable $hide is the Id# 

then in my php code is this 
$qwe = "INSERT INTO `enrolled` SELECT * FROM `new` WHERE `id` = '$hide' "; 
and the table 'enrolled ' still shows nothing :(

Comment: From where should the value come from for $hide? User input or anything else?

Comment: the value of $hide came from value of the textbox , the text is not a user input , i just use textbox to see what is the value of the ID. 
the textbox is located in the WHILE loop, you can check it.